# expected primary expression before '=' token

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
int i=2 ,j =3;
      int total ;
    total + = i--;
    cout << total  << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

please help me I use codeblocks and i have error

```
expected primary expression before '=' token )
 in  line  6  (total + = i-- )
```

Why?

Comment: remove the space between `+` and `=`

Comment: this is really fast help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get rid of the space between `+` and `=`:

```
total += i--;
```

Answer (score 6):

It's "+=" and not "+ =".

It's just like you wrote "f o o" instead of "foo".